# Optimal meeting point in an directed graph having 2 starting vertices

Tags: graph, distance, shortest-path

What algorithm should I use if in a directed graph I want to find the shortest paths, having 2 starting vertices, so that the paths meet and both have the minimum distance for this to happen.

Comment: If I understood your requirements correctly, it seems like you don't need to calculate 2 paths.  Calculate the shortest path between the two starting vertices, then find the median vertex based on it's weight.

Comment: Oops -- that wouldn't work on a directed graph.  Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an All-Pairs-Shortest-Path, find common endpoints, and then find the minimum of (distance(vertex1,endpoint)+distance(vertex2,endpoint)) for all possible endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I would use Dijkstra's to get minimal distance trees for both starting vertices, then add the two distance vectors together and take the minimum. C.B.'s answer is fine, but you don't need the shortest distances between all pairs, so there's some redundant work there.